# Would you use "used in the real world" or "used in real world"?

Tags: articles

I have written a computer tutorial, but I am not sure if I have this sentence correct:

"Build three high-quality computer applications used in the real world!"

I am trying to say that these computer applications that are to be built are not just trivial toy applications, but applications used in reality in the industry. Would you write "used in real world" instead without the "the"? Any other third alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, I would use the article. (I can't actually think of any situation where it would be used as a mass noun.)

However, if it were me, I would actually rephrase the sentence and turn *real world* into an adjective:

> Build three high-quality real-world computer applications.

Answer (score 1):

> "the real world" is a noun phrase.
>
> "real-world" is an adjectival phrase.

Thus:

"Please describe three applications that are used in the real word."

or

"Please describe three real-world applications.